# How can I delete all the records which varchar contains any of a list of elements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete, varchar

I have Trees:

```
Trees(IDNodo, Path, color, ....)
```

IDMytable is a autonumeric (bigint) and path is a varchar(MAX) that contains the complete  route to a node in my tree.

I would like to delete all the nodes and subnodes, so I can do:

```
delete from trees where Path like '%[IDNode]'%
```

This delete the node and all the subnodes.

But if I want to delete all the nodes that have an specific property, I can get these nodes with this query:

```
select * from Trees where Color = 'Red';
```

This gives me all the nodes in all the trees that are red. I get many IDNodes. Then I want to delete all the subnodes of each red node.

```
delete from trees where Path like IN (select * from Trees where Color = 'Red');
```

If path is a long, for example, I can use "IN" but I don't know if there is an equivalent when the field is a varchar.

I would like to avoid the use of a recursive procedure.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem; why can't you just do delete from trees where color='Red'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make your delete query like below

```
delete from trees where Path 
IN (select Path from Trees where Color = 'Red');
```

But the above query is same as saying

```
delete from Trees where Color = 'Red';
```

Comment: But if the color can be red, black ahdn ywllow for example? Three colors.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, in that case use `IN` operator and say `Color in ('red','black','yellow')`